# For any $n^2+1$ closed intervals of $\mathbb R$, prove that $n+1$ of the intervals share a point or $n+1$ of the intervals are disjoint

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Stuck on a question from 'Introduction to Combinatorics by Martin J. Erickson'.

Q: For any $n^2+1$ closed intervals of $\mathbb R$, prove that $n+1$ of the intervals share a point or $n+1$ of the intervals are disjoint.

I think we can use the Erdos-Szekeres Theorem: relating the usual series of integers to the closed intervals, and the decreasing/increasing monotonic sequences somehow to the two outcomes, but I am stuck on how to technically do this.

Could we measure the 'distance' between the intervals? Creating a decreasing sequence ensuring they'd be close enough to share a point, and an increasing sequence that would ensure they are far enough away to be disjoint?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this isn't actually true, at least without some additional conditions. Of course, my gut could be wrong.

Comment: If we create a graph $G$ whose vertices are the $n^2+1$ closed intervals of $R$, the problem then asks to show that either their is a clique of size $n+1$ or there there is an independent set of size $n+1$. The problem seems to be related to [Ramsey theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a sketch of a proof; I’ve left two significant points for you to prove.

- First prove that if $\mathscr{I}$ is a finite collection of closed intervals such that no two intervals in $\mathscr{I}$ are disjoint, then $\bigcap\mathscr{I}\ne\varnothing$; this can be done by induction on $|\mathscr{I}|$. (It’s also a special case of [Helly’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly's_theorem).)

Now let $\mathscr{J}_0$ be a family of $n^2+1$ closed intervals, and suppose that no $n+1$ members of $\mathscr{J}_0$ share a point. Given a non-empty $\mathscr{J}_k$ for some $k\ge 0$, let $\mathscr{I}_k$ be a maximal subfamily of $\mathscr{J}_k$ such that no two intervals in $\mathscr{I}_k$ are disjoint, and let $\mathscr{J}_{k+1}=\mathscr{J}_k\setminus\mathscr{I}_k$. Clearly there is a largest $m$ such that $\mathscr{J}_m\ne\varnothing$, and $\{\mathscr{I}_0,\ldots,\mathscr{I}_m\}$ is therefore a partition of $\mathscr{F}$ into $m+1$ parts. The result at the top implies that $\bigcap\mathscr{I}_k\ne\varnothing$ for $k=0,\ldots,m$, so by hypothesis $|\mathscr{I}_k|\le n$ for $k=0,\ldots,m$, and it follows that $m\ge n$.

For $k=0,\ldots,m$ let $C_k=\bigcap\mathscr{I}_k$; $C_k$ is a closed interval (possibly degenerate), and $\{C_0,\ldots,I_m\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family. For $k=0,\ldots,m$ there is an $i_k\in\mathscr{I}_k$ such that $\max I_k=\max C_k$.

- To complete the argument, show that $\{I_0,\ldots,I_m\}$ is a family of at least $n+1$ pairwise disjoint members of $\mathscr{J}_0$.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using the Erdos-Szekeres theorem.

Let $f$ be an unknown but bijective mapping from the collection of the closed sets (call them $C_i,\ i=1,2,\cdots$) to natural numbers. We can make $f$ bijective because we know that the collection of closed sets is countable since each closed set can be written as intersection of countable number of closed sets each of which can be identified with some rational number in $(0,1)$.

Now, Let $f$ be defined in a way such that $f(C_i)\le f(C_j)$, iff $C_i\cap C_j\ne \emptyset$, and $f(C_i)>f(C_j)$, otherwise. Then, we can use [Erdos-Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) with $r=s=n+1$, which then, using the bijectivity of mapping $f$ gives the result.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. We know that the collection of closed sets is countable because there are only $n^2+1$ of them, don't we? Also, I think in general such an $f$ won't exist (even assuming that you mean us to take $i < j$ in your definition).

Comment: The part where I used the closedness of the sets $C_i$ was supposed to explain whether we can choose such an $f$ as defined in the answer. We are given only a finite collection of closed sets, true, but for the definition of $f$ to hold, it has to hold over the collection of **all possible closed sets**, so it becomes impossible to define such a mapping if the collection itself is uncountable.

Comment: I made necessary edits to make it more sense.